# How to make sense of Ethernet adapter naming in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet

When using Ethernet adaptors in Windows 10 they seem to have completely different names depending on how you look at them. In the normal adapter setting I see e.g. this

[image]

and in the devices settings I see this

[image]

My *guess* is that "Ethernet 2" is "Realtek Controller #3". Is there any way to make the naming more consistent? Any settings I can use? Or do I have to continue guessing with these always-after-reboot-changing-adapter-names?

Comment: what does `ipconfig /all` tell you?

Comment: Ah nice! Here I have a mapping between those names. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: The names from device settings are literally in your first screenshot as the last line of every adapter...

Comment: @Silbee But I cannot see the complete name! Parts are missing.

Comment: Like any other desktop icon element in windows, if it ends with { ... } you can hover over it with the mouse cursor, it displays the full string.

Answer (score 1):

### Do I have to continue guessing with these changing adapter names?

You can get the mapping by running:

```
ipconfig /all
```

which displays full configuration information.

See: [ipconfig - IP configuration command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html)